# Eliminate date in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I wish to eliminate the dates of my list of BTC prices so that I only have the prices left (I do not need the dates for the purpose of my analysis). The list appears as follows:

[image: BTC/USD]

Is there an easy command to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: `Last /@ `?${}$

Comment: I was running Flatten[..] and then I need every 4 element of the list for the whole dataset. Last[..] gives me only the last entry.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform 
Thank you! I actually used: 

**Last /@ Partition[Flatten[Btc], 4]**

And it worked :)

Comment: `data[[All,2]]`

Comment: @Waie No need to `Partition`. `Last /@ Btc` should work just fine. See also Roman's suggestion, `Btc[[All,2]]`.

Comment: Use the Span operators.  See documentation.  Here is a simple example of your data:

    myList = Flatten[{{{2011, 9, 10}, 5.97}, {{2011, 10, 
      11},6.01}, {{2012, 9, 8}, 8.3}}]
    myList[[4 ;; Length[myList] ;; 4]]

Comment: Or `btc[[All, 2;;]]` if you have more columns. Look up the [documentation on `Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I frequently use this shorthand (use "-1" for last or could also use "2"):

```
Btc[[;;,-1]]
```